# Transfer Objects, Spring MVC, Architectural

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, architecture

My simple Spring MVC application has the following tiers: **(0) web tier with plain JSPs (1) controller, (2)service, (3) repository, (4) model**. I am using Spring Data JPA for the repositories. I think about **what the reason of having data transfer objects (DTO) is** in my scenario as the client needs all the fields of the entity classes. It just cuts the performance and causes development effort to repackage everything.

I know that **(a) DTO helps to decouple the tiers**, and **(b) the database table structure will be hidden from the client** that can be useful for security reasons. However, (b) does not seem to be an issue in my appliaction because the client needs all the data. As far as decoupling the tiers is concerned, any change in the entity class should also be applied to the DTO and the client as well.

I would be interested in how you see providing the entities as model attributes to the client instead of DTOs. Thanks for the posts also in advance.

Comment: Avoiding DTO hell would be my preference but all a matter of opinion.

Comment: You can construct everything in the model objects, usage of DTOs is optional.

Comment: Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 1):

[*Separation of model and view*](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/stringtemplate.html) provides many benefits such as freedom to modify both without affecting the other. Of course, in some cases, like yours, both model and view could be same.

Comment: In addition to more code, it can also lead to duplication, performance overheads and an anaemic domain model.